# How to type the date mm/dd/yyyy(validation applied) in that entry field xamarin forms

Tags: date, validation, xamarin, xamarin.forms, keyboard

[image]I have an requirement. When the user tap on the calendar image only at that date picker will open - working fine. If user click entry means number keyboard will open and they will be able to type the date mm/dd/yyyy(validation applied) in that entry field.

I need a functionality to achieve enter month,date,year using customized entry. If click the entry, i am going to enter month(1 to 12) then forward slash(/) should be add. same like date(1 to 31) entered after that forward slash(/) should be add. Then year add. Like this requirement i am looking for.

How to achieve this functionality for both android and ios using xamarin forms?

Comment: You already asked this today and it was closed.  Please do not post duplicates.  I pointed you to an existing question that showed how to created an Entry with a Button

Comment: I need a functionality to achieve enter month,date,year using customized entry. If click the entry, i am going to enter month(1 to 12) then forward slash(/) should be add. same like date(1 to 31) entered after that forward slash(/) should be add. Then year add. Like this requirement.
How to achieve this functionality for both android and ios using xamarin forms?
Please provide me the solution.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/maskedbehavior

Comment: How to customize the MaskedBehavior Mask value?

Comment: Did you try the [example code in the official sample](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Behaviors/MaskedBehaviorPage.xaml#L40)?